# Scrollable x axis with chart.js 2.1.4

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I have a line graph with lot of points to plot
I want x axis to be scrollable

I have already looked few [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35854244/how-can-i-create-a-horizontal-scrolling-chart-js-line-chart-with-a-locked-y-axis) but they are providing solution with old versions of chart js.

**Is there any option to get scrollable x axis in chart.js version 2?**
And
**How can i get width of content in y axis in chart.js version 2?**
if there is no direct option to get scrollable x axis, I can copy content in Y-axis region and draw image in other canvas.

Answer (score 1):

My answer on a related question will help you. In my example I have made the Y axis scrollable, but this could easily be applied to the X axis too.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51282003/10060003

JS fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/EmmaLouise/eb1aqpx8/3/

I am using the animation onComplete and onProgress options to redraw the axis that I want to scroll with the chart. (See https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/animations.html).

```
$(function () {
    var rectangleSet = false;

    var canvasTest = $('#chart-Test');
    var chartTest = new Chart(canvasTest, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: chartData,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        responsive: true,
        options: {
            tooltips: {
                titleFontSize: 0,
                titleMarginBottom: 0,
                bodyFontSize: 12
            },
            legend: {
                display: false
            },
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        fontSize: 12,
                        display: false
                    }
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        fontSize: 12,
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }]
            },
            animation: {
                onComplete: function () {
                    if (!rectangleSet) {
                        var scale = window.devicePixelRatio;                       

                        var sourceCanvas = chartTest.chart.canvas;
                        var copyWidth = chartTest.scales['y-axis-0'].width - 10;
                        var copyHeight = chartTest.scales['y-axis-0'].height + chartTest.scales['y-axis-0'].top + 10;

                        var targetCtx = document.getElementById("axis-Test").getContext("2d");

                        targetCtx.scale(scale, scale);
                        targetCtx.canvas.width = copyWidth * scale;
                        targetCtx.canvas.height = copyHeight * scale;

                        targetCtx.canvas.style.width = `${copyWidth}px`;
                        targetCtx.canvas.style.height = `${copyHeight}px`;
                        targetCtx.drawImage(sourceCanvas, 0, 0, copyWidth * scale, copyHeight * scale, 0, 0, copyWidth * scale, copyHeight * scale);

                        var sourceCtx = sourceCanvas.getContext('2d');

                        // Normalize coordinate system to use css pixels.

                        sourceCtx.clearRect(0, 0, copyWidth * scale, copyHeight * scale);
                        rectangleSet = true;
                    }
                },
                onProgress: function () {
                    if (rectangleSet === true) {
                        var copyWidth = chartTest.scales['y-axis-0'].width;
                        var copyHeight = chartTest.scales['y-axis-0'].height + chartTest.scales['y-axis-0'].top + 10;

                        var sourceCtx = chartTest.chart.canvas.getContext('2d');
                        sourceCtx.clearRect(0, 0, copyWidth, copyHeight);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```