# AngularJs charts fix y-axis

Tags: angularjs, scroll, charts

Does anyone have any idea if I can fix de y-axis when I scroll to the right on Angular ChartsJS library ? I have searched in the documentation, but I found nothing. Can I fix it some other way ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mbhavfwm/) .

originally answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35935939/5198430).

```
<div class="chartWrapper">
 <div class="chartAreaWrapper">
    <canvas id="myChart" height="300" width="1200"></canvas>
 </div>
 <canvas id="myChartAxis" height="300" width="0"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: I am working with chart js 2. Do you have any idea how can I adapt this

Comment: If I use this, I get this error : angular.js:13236 TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(HTMLImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap)'