# how to make a chart.js bar chart scrollable

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, chart.js

Does anyone know how I can make charts that are made using [chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#chart-configuration-creating-a-chart-with-options) scrollable.
I have a bar chart which has a very long list of categories on the x-axis. When I change the browser view to mobile screen the labels on the x-axis go into each other and it becomes impossible to read the different categories.

I'm looking for a solution for this by making the chart scrollable horizontally. Is that possible??

Comment: I found this online but im not sure if this works with your charts.js version. Which one is it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35854244/how-can-i-create-a-horizontal-scrolling-chart-js-line-chart-with-a-locked-y-axis Good luck

Comment: try https://jsfiddle.net/rbdqxfzL/140/ This is not a perfect solution because it is parent `div` which is made scrollable and not the chart itself. However, the solution should work fine for very significantly large data set as well

Answer (score 8):

ChartJs doesn't support scrollable `axis` natively. ChartJs charts are responsive and change width according to parent container. You can use this to create a large parent container and have your ChartJs canvas inside it. `overflow: auto` property with little markup should give you the desired result.

See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rbdqxfzL/140

HTML

```
<div class="chartWrapper">
  <div class="chartAreaWrapper">
    <canvas id="chart" height="400" width="15000"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.chartWrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.chartWrapper > canvas {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.chartAreaWrapper {
  width: 15000px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

Comment: this is a good example i suppose but the y axis isn't fixed when you scroll

Comment: @Jereme if you use css ```{overflow-x: scroll}``` it should keep y fixed

Answer (score 0):

Use the [chartjs-plugin-zoom plugin](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-zoom) for Chart.js where you can use zooming and padding to suit your needs.

```
plugins: {        
   zoom: {
      pan: {
         enabled: true
      },
      zoom: {
         enabled: true
      }
   }
}
```