# Chartjs v2 on retina display has label size issue (text is too large)

Tags: javascript, chart.js, retina-display

I'm using [chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/) with the latest v2.7.1 release. I followed this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z5gg4f2s/) example for creating a fixed Y-Axis effect when scrolling. It works great but there is one issue with Retina displays (iPhones, Macbooks, etc).

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");

        var chart = {
        options: {
          responsive: true,
          maintainAspectRatio: false,
          animation: {
                    
                    onComplete: function(animation) {
                        var sourceCanvas = myLiveChart.chart.canvas;
                        var copyWidth = myLiveChart.scales['y-axis-0'].width - 10;
                        var copyHeight = myLiveChart.scales['y-axis-0'].height + myLiveChart.scales['y-axis-0'].top + 10;
                        var targetCtx = document.getElementById("myChartAxis").getContext("2d");
                        targetCtx.canvas.width = copyWidth;
                targetCtx.drawImage(sourceCanvas, 0, 0, copyWidth, copyHeight, 0, 0, copyWidth, copyHeight);
                    }
                }
      },
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: "My First dataset",
                    fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
                    strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                    pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                    pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
                }
            ]
        }};

   var myLiveChart = new Chart(ctx, chart);

 setInterval(function () {
  myLiveChart.data.datasets[0].data.push(Math.random() * 100);
 myLiveChart.data.labels.push("Test");
  var newwidth = $('.chartAreaWrapper2').width() +60;
  $('.chartAreaWrapper2').width(newwidth);
   $('.chartAreaWrapper').animate({scrollLeft:newwidth});
  
    }, 5000);
```

```css
 .chartWrapper {
            position: relative;
            
        }

        .chartWrapper > canvas {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            pointer-events:none;
        }
.chartAreaWrapper {
          overflow-x: scroll;
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .chartAreaWrapper2 {
          
            position: relative;
            height: 300px;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
 <div class="chartWrapper">
      <div class="chartAreaWrapper">
        <div class="chartAreaWrapper2">
            <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
        </div>
      </div>
        
        <canvas id="myChartAxis" height="300" width="0"></canvas>
    </div>
```

If you view the code snippet (and wait the 5 seconds for a scroll trigger) on Retina screen, the Y-axis labels are very large, and also appear cut-off as if it wasn't completely rendered. The same view on a non-retina screen looks fine. Are there any js/css workarounds for the sizing issue on Retina screens or any specific chart.js workarounds?

(Credit to this stackoverflow post for [the code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35854244/how-can-i-create-a-horizontal-scrolling-chart-js-line-chart-with-a-locked-y-axis#comment69236823_35935939))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also ran into this issue, the original fiddle works well except that it is not responsive.

The key is that the original fiddle does not take into account the `devicePixelRatio` the same way as the chart using the `helpers.retinaScale` method from ChartJS core.

After several hours of fiddling, here is the surprisingly simple answer: https://jsfiddle.net/4ydfo4xo/

When copying the scales from the original chart, the `devicePixelRatio` must be applied to the sourceWidth and sourceHeight arguments of `drawImage`

Specifically the pixel ratio is accessed using

```
var pixelRatio = myLiveChart.chart.currentDevicePixelRatio;
```

and then the `drawImage` arguments are changed..

```
targetCtx.drawImage(sourceCanvas, 0, 0, copyWidth * pixelRatio, copyHeight * pixelRatio, 0, 0, copyWidth, copyHeight);
```