# How to make react chartjs chart scrollable

Tags: chart.js, react-chartjs

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35854244/how-can-i-create-a-horizontal-scrolling-chart-js-line-chart-with-a-locked-y-axis) shows how to make a chartjs chart scrollable. Can someone tell how to achieve this using react-chartjs-2?

Comment: Have you got the Solution?

Comment: Any concrete solution to this thread?